# building data using dataframe with python 3.7

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hi i tried to write some data about students using dataframe 
this is my code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    data={"students":["aj","mark","bob","rachel","steven"],
    "math":[98,50,23,72,87],
    "science":[96,45,76,54,1],
    "sports":["base","swim","tt","bad","tae"]}
    students=pd.DataFrame(data,columns= 
    ["students","math","science","sports"])
    print(students)
```

but i keep getting this eror :

```
    result = Series(result, index=obj.index, name=obj.name, copy=False)
    TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

whats is the prolem with my code?
thanks for the help :)

Comment: You must have created a list called `Series` somewhere, and it's shadowing the constructor.

Comment: Are you using Spyder by any chance?

Comment: @roganjosh  yes im using spyder

Comment: @ElizaRomanski click in the ipython console window and use `ctrl` + `.`. Restart the kernel